# Различие скорости суммы цифр через строку и через алгоритм

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм

Можете объяснить, почему возникает такая огромная разница в скорости вычисления этих двух функций? Мне казалось, что и строки, и числа реализованы на С, но неужели из-за того что они безразмерные настолько дольше получается или в чем разница?

```
def sum_str(x):
    cnt = 0
    for digit in str(x):
        cnt += int(digit)
    return cnt

def sum_digits(x):
    cnt = 0
    while x > 0:
        cnt += x % 10
        x //= 10
    return cnt

>>> number = random.randrange(10**10**5)
>>> %%time sum_str(number) # 700 ms~
>>> %%time sum_digits(number) # 13.8s~
```

Comment: через строки `sum_str` получается в 20 раз быстрее, чем через числа `sum_digits` - 0.7 секунд против 13.8 секунд. А разговор, будто наоборот.

Comment: Да, через строки получается быстрее, я если честно не понял @mrEvgenX, он поддерживает мою точку зрения или нет... Можете попробовать у себя, запустить, у меня так: https://prnt.sc/umiezs

Answer (score 2):

Дело в том, что *длинная арифметика* - крайне сложное и затратное дело, особенно деление. Так что там, где способ со строками тратит время только на вычисление и создание строки, а далее идет простейшее суммирование малых чисел, выбираемых из строки по сути мгновенно, второй способ для получения очередной цифры проводит массу вычислений с очень большими числами...

В то время как все эти промежуточные вычисления по сути не нужны и при работе со строкой не выполняются.

Comment: Это странно, взятие остатка и целочисленное деление казалось мне куда более быстрым занятием, т.к. оперирует только с концом числа, я не знаю как точно она реализована, но если там просто динамический массив цифр, то кажется достаточно убрать ссылку на последние цифры и все будет ок...

Comment: @ВладиславХарламов Хранится-то длинное число совсем даже не в виде строки и не в десятичной записи, а в массиве 4-байтовых целых чисел, например. И как вы при этом будете работать *"с последними цифрами"*? Далее, неужели, по-вашму, код должен смотреть - и, такой: "ага, тут деление на 10, значит, надо просто убрать последнюю цифру... а тут - на 123, тут надо считать полностью..."? Вы себе это так представляете? :) Да, интереса ради - посмотрите, тут бывали вопросы о длинной арифметике, и сравнивались скорости при массиве цифр и при массиве целых чисел (правда, на C/C++). Очень показательно...